# Paper Sizes on Android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, printing

On the Android print screen, I only see American paper sizes (Letter, Legal etc.). Is there a way to add or switch to ISO sizes (A4, A5 etc.)?

Comment: For everything else, I have my phone set to American English with metric units.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is linked to the language you've set in your Android device.

Most probably you set the language as "English (United-States)" and with these settings you only get the American format in you "Paper Size" dropdown.

Therefore, if you want to have the ISO size but still keep your phone in English, you just have to set the language of it in "English (United Kingdom)" and your problem will be solved.

Manipulation :

**Settings > Language & input > Language > English (United Kingdom)**

Close your apps and try again, in "Paper Size" you should now see the ISO formats.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's up to the developer to provide whichever [print job](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintJob.html)  [attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintAttributes.html) they want to support for their app. The ISO, Japanese, and other media sizes are defined in Android's API [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintAttributes.MediaSize.html) and I think it would be up to the developer to use them.

The developer can modify the print dialog for the user via a custom [print document adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html) that can include a set of default print attributes that are appropriate for what's being printed, and I bet this is where they'd include the ISO sizes.

Unless someone has a better solution (and who knows-- there could simply be an option somewhere to change based on location or language that I just don't know about), your best bet may be to contact the developer of the app you're using and ask them to add the ISO sizing attributes to the list of default print attributes.

Comment: Hm, according to that documentation, the app only sets the default. I did try changing the language of the phone to German and now it shows only ISO sizes, so it seems to be linked directly to the language.

Comment: Interesting.  So does that work as a solution then?  I think the developer can make changes to include those ISO formats as well...

Comment: Well, it will get me through the printing process, though I think it's rediculous that I have to change the language every time I want to. :/